# Hyperref and bibtex footnotes

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, hyperref, footnotes

It is my first question I ask here on StackExchange, without a MWE because right now it makes no sense to show any, because it is a general compilation problem. I think one of the rather known bugs of the Hyperref package?

**Problem:** I write my thesis in history in Latex and in history we use plenty of long footnotes. I really appreciate that hyperref links footnotes to the first time the source was used, and would not like to miss it.
Nonetheless, there is one substantial problem:
If footnotes surpass one page in the pdf compiled document, the footnote link covers at some point the entire page that follows, until the footnote ends in the same page.

I know that there are is hyperref command \PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref} to deactivate the function in footnotes, but is there an alternative way to keep these links in footnotes? Did anyone come up with an elegant solution to use footnotes and hyperref without having these problems?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

[image]

Comment: This is not a problem of hyperfootnotes, the problem is that you have a citation with a link which is broken over the page. There is nothing hyperref can do currently, as it is a problem of the pdftex primitive. The next pdftex will have a primitive which will allow to interrupt such a link, but it will require changes to the output routine of latex to use it, so it is a long term project.

Comment: Ulrike thank you for your reply. Now I have a clear picture about the problem and am confident that it was not a mistake on my part and part of the pdftex primitve development. kind regards!

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem of `hyperfootnotes`, the problem is that you have a citation with a link which is broken over the page. There is nothing `hyperref` can do currently, as it is a problem of the pdftex primitive to create links: it grabs everything in  between. The next pdftex version will have a primitive which will allow to interrupt such a link, but it will require changes to the output routine of LaTeX to use it, so it is a long term project.